# Too many open files; nested exception is java.net.SocketException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

In my current spring boot based, project we are getting error in production environment as **"Too many open files; nested exception is java.net.SocketException:"**

```
Too many open files; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Too
many open files
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
     at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:460)
     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:587)
     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)
     at
sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
     at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
     at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
     at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
```

This error appears when we make http call to another micro service based rest api in same network with resttemplate library. Recently we have modified resttemplate to add timeout in it, I suspect some issue might be there in code. I have added the bean defination logic/code below. Any help will be appreciated. Note that I already referenced another stackoverflow question for same error but that did not help.

Here, we make restTemplate.exchange method call from caller service in order to make http call to another service.

**Question: is there any problem with below configuration ?**

We are calling this method to get resttemplate instance for each request. One more point to note that when I use singleton or single instance of restmplate for all requests then this issue was not seen anymore.

```
 public RestTemplate getRestTemplate(int timeoutMs) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(timeoutMs);
        clientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(timeoutMs);
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(clientHttpRequestFactory);
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(appClientInterceptor));
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(appClientErrorHanlder);
        return restTemplate;
    }
```

Few details about environment is as below :
Spring boot version: 1.5.8 
Java version: 1.8
OS: Linux

Comment: Please refer to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/26214#issuecomment-856214007 I think it may be your case

Comment: one more point to note that when I switch to singletone resttemplate instance then this issue did not happen anymore. But  when we created separate instance of resttemplate for each request then it was started giving too many open file issue.

Answer (score 0):

It was strange but finally I resolved this issue by using singleton RestTemplate and singleton resttemplate builder.

While using new resttemplate instance created from rest template builder, it creates some **connection pooling for each request** and those connections aren't closed by default.